# Неправильный фон subMenu (подменю) в ActionBar

Tags: java, android, actionbar, menu, popupmenu

**Дано**:

ActionBar сделан с помощью Toolbar из AppCompat либы.

**Проблема**:

SubMenu показывается с прозрачным фоном. А меню первого уровня работают как надо.

**Подозрения**:

1) Что-то не так в стилях (они ниже).

2) Косяк ToolBar и/или AppCompat (v21) либы.

3) <зачёркнуто>андроид не работает!!!11<\зачёркнуто> вопрошающий не до конца распрямил руки.

---

В стилях вот что:

```
<style name="ThemeLight" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
<item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/OdnakoPopupMenuLight</item>
<item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/OdnakoDropDownListViewLight</item>
</style>

<style name="OdnakoPopupMenuLight" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/material_grey_400</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/material_grey_400</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/material_grey_800</item>
</style>

<style name="OdnakoDropDownListViewLight" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/material_grey_400</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/material_grey_400</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/material_grey_800</item>
</style>
```

В этих ваших гуглах советуют стиль ListView поменять, но оно не помагает.

**Итого**:

***Гугл бессилен***, **я бессилен**. *Помогите*(

Comment: Эх... Этак половина моих вопросов скоро будет без единого ответа(
 Неужто придётся менять две кнопки подменю на одну верхнего уровня? =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге всё дело было в отсутствии одного атрибута в стиле, а именно:

```
<item name="android:itemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_light</item>
```

Отчего-то без оного в некоторых случаях фон элементов контекстного меню становился прозрачным, хотя остальные свойства селектора работали. Т.е. при выделении, фокусе, его потере и нажатии цвет менялся, а по дефолту прозрачный был.